# Do ViewModels have different fields than a Models?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

I am wondering what properties,method, or variables in a typical ViewModel make it different from a Model.

Comment: sometimes, otherwise, what would be the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVVM explanation:

A model is about your domain. Classic examples are customers, orders, order-details etc. These are oblivious to your user interface. Often models doesn't contain any code that are delegated to some services.

A view-model is about how your present what is in the view-model. Say you have a view with an order with details. The view-model may contain state about the current order-detail and other visible state like should the delete button be enabled? It also references the models presented by the view-model e.g. an order and a collection of order-details. The view-model also has ways to perform actions like deleting the current order-detail etc.

Answer (score 2):

In MVVM, the "Model" stands for the entire domain model whereas a ViewModel is specific to a particular View and contains only those fields/properties that are displayed or modified in the View.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx (the latter is about using MVVM in WPF -- as in ASP.NET, usually MVC is used rather than MVVM).

Comment: Also a ViewModel should only contains Information for your view. A ViewModel shouldn't contain any methods or logic!

Comment: @middelpat: How are you supposed to create a ViewModel without any logic. Where do you put the logic for the "delete" button etc.?

Comment: Logic for UI elements is put in the View. The View can then call methods on the Model (in MVVM) or on the Controller (in MVC).

Comment: The view can call the delete method on the controller since we talk about ViewModels i assume we're talking about MVC

Comment: @RoyDictus: I guess this can soon detoriate into a subjective discussion, but to many MVVM is about not having any code or logic in the view making the view-model unit testable.

Comment: @middelpat: OK, this explains the confusion. I'm talking about MVVM.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: Indeed, but of course when the View contains UI elements with which users interact, at least somewhere you must have event handlers... In my experience (MVC) Views are not unit-tested, Controllers are; but like you say, this is probably a matter of style and preference; different teams will choose different styles.

Answer (score 1):

View models are "optimized" to be bound to view.
So, in WPF they contains properties, specific to the presentation layer, e.g. commands, image sources, etc.

Also, view models can be decorated with data annotations attributes, which is bad practice for *models*; they can implement any interfaces (like `IDataErrorInfo`), which are intended to be used in UI; or they can implement any undo/redo functionality.

All this stuff is harmful for domain models.